# R - Improve speed of do.call / by function

Tags: r, functional-programming, tapply, do.call

I've gotten fairly good with the *apply family of functions, and I've recently learned to use the `do.call("rbind", by(...` as a wrapper for `tapply`.  I'm working with a large data set (Compustat) and I have a function (see below) that generates a new column of lagged variables which I later attach to the main data frame `df`.

My problem is that it is **extremely** slow.  I create about two dozen lagged variables, and the processing in this function takes approximately 1.5 hours because there are 350,000+ firm-year observations in the data set.

Can anyone help improve the speed of this function without losing the aspects that I find desirable:

```
#' lag vector of unknown size (for do.call-rbind-by: using datadate to track)

lag.vec <- function(x){
   x   <- x[order(x$datadate), ] # sort data into ascending by date

   var <- x[,2]  # the specific variable name in data.frame x hereby ignored
   var.name <- paste(names(x)[2], "lag", sep = '.')       # keep variable name

   if(length(var)>1){  # no lagging if single observation

      lagged   <- c(NA, var[1:(length(var)-1)])
      datelag  <- c(x$datadate[1], x$datadate[1:(length(x$datadate) - 1)])
      datediff <- x$datadate - datelag

      y <- data.frame(x$datadate, datediff,  lagged)  # join lagged variable and difference in YYYYMMDD data

      y$lagged[y$datediff >= 20000 & !is.na(y$datediff)] <- NA   # 2 or more full years difference

      y <- y[, c('x.datadate', 'lagged')]
      names(y)  <- c("datadate", var.name)

   } else {  y <- c(x$datadate[1], NA); names(y) <- c("datadate", var.name) }
   return(y)
}
```

I then call this function in a command separately for each variable that I want to generate a lagged series for (here I use the `ni` variable as an example):

```
ni_lag      <- do.call('rbind', by(df[ , c('datadate', 'ni')],  df$gvkey, lag.vec))
```

where `gvkey` is the ID number for the particular firm and `datadate` is an 8-digit integer of the form `YYYYMMDD`.

The approach was much faster when I used a simpler function:

```
lag.vec.seq <- function(x){#' lag vector when all data points are present, in order

if(length(x)>1){
      y <- c(NA, x[1:(length(x)-1)])
  } else {y <- NA}
  return(y)
}
```

along with the `tapply` command in something like

```
ni_lag      <- as.vector(unlist(tapply(df$ni,  df$gvkey, lag.vec.seq)))
```

As you can see the main difference is that the `tapply` approach doesn't include any `datadate` information and so the function assumes that all data are sequential (i.e., there are no missing years in the dataframe).  Since I know there are missing years, I built the `do.call`-`by` function to account for that.

Some notes:

1) The first `order` command in the function is probably unnecessary since my data is ordered by `gvkey` and `datadate` in advance (e.g. `df <- df[order(df$gvkey, df$datadate), ]`).  However, I'm always a bit afraid that `R` messies up my row ordering when I use functional programming like this.  Is that an unfounded fear?

2) Identifying what is slowing down the processing would be very helpful. Is it the renaming of variables? The creation of a new data frame in the function? Or is the `do.call` with `by` just typically (much) slower than `tapply`?

Thank you!

Comment: For fast split-apply-combine you should use package data.table or package dplyr. Don't try reinventing the wheel. `by` is actually quite slow for data with many groups, as is `tapply`.

Comment: Is that so? I thought the dplyr package was slower than the *apply family of functions (and `by` as well).  Okay, I'll try `ddply` and see if that speeds things up. Thanks.

Comment: There's `plyr` and there's `dplyr` - the latter is newer and much faster than `plyr`. And `ddply` is from `plyr`